# Windows computer using Linux GPU and CPU

Tags: linux, windows

Is it possible to have a computer that runs Windows, and make it run a game or program. Then make the Windows computer use the GPU and CPU of a sperate Linux computer. Would this be possible?, and how efficient would it be?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just send the data to the other computer, do the processing there and send the data back.

You are probably doing this all the time: when you type something into your search bar on your windows computer, the search string gets sent to google who processes it on their linux computers' CPUs and send it back to your computer.

As far as *efficiency* goes, you need to specify measures for "efficiency".
Latency will be horrible (compared to e.g. a CPU on the same host).

Comment: Is there a program which can help with this, or if I need to make it do you have any tips?

Comment: a browser and a webserver?